# Advantages of using short name variables

Tags: variables, language-agnostic

I always try to give a self-explanatory name to my variables. Silly example: I prefer to use 'word' instead of 'w' in order to make my code more readable.

If there is just a couple of variables, I guess the impact in the efficiency of the program will be completely insignificant, but, what if my program has XX/Xk lines of code?

Comment: I would only worry if my code is JS (where minification comes.). But in any other programming language, it is a balance between short-name and understand-ability. If a variable name makes more sense to a developer who looks at the code later, I don't mind if it is long.

Answer (score 1):

The shorter variable names don't increase the performance in practice.
After declaration, these variables get a unique memory address and the reference will by memory address ,  not the variable name.

The longer and more meaningful variable names helps to understand the code.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the language but truthfully using larger variable names does not slow down the program enough to justify using w vs word because when future programmers see you code they need to understand what you're doing. In a loop or such, x is fine you don't need "counter". If you're typing out last_login_date, last_login is better but w vs word is a terrible convention idea.